# Roblox leaderstat not loading in

Tags: lua, roblox

So I need five leaderstats for my game, I am able to load four of them but for some reason, I can't load in the deaths leaderstat. This is my code:

```
type void = nil

local function addstat(leaderstats: Folder, statname: string, stattype: string): void
    assert(leaderstats:IsA("Folder"), `Invalid argument 1 to 'addstat': Expected Folder, got {if typeof(leaderstats) == "Instance" then leaderstats.ClassName else typeof(leaderstats)}`)
    assert(typeof(statname) == "string", `Invalid argument 2 to 'addstat': Expected string, got {if typeof(statname) == "Instance" then statname.ClassName else typeof(statname)}`)
    assert(typeof(stattype) == "string", `Invalid argument 3 to 'addstat': Expected string, got {if typeof(stattype) == "Instance" then stattype.ClassName else typeof(stattype)}`)
    local success: bool, stat: ValueBase = pcall(function()
        return Instance.new(stattype);
    end)
    assert(success, "Error adding stat: Failed to create instance, invalid type?");
    assert(stat:IsA("ValueBase"), "Error adding stat: Stat type must be a Value!");
    
    stat.Name = statname;
    stat.Parent = leaderstats;
end

game.Players.PlayerAdded:Connect(function(player: Player): void
    local leaderstats: Folder = Instance.new("Folder");
    
    addstat(leaderstats, "CryptoCoin", "NumberValue");
    addstat(leaderstats, "GemCoins", "NumberValue");
    addstat(leaderstats, "Wins", "NumberValue");
    addstat(leaderstats, "Kills", "NumberValue");
    addstat(leaderstats, "Deaths", "NumberValue");

    leaderstats.Name = "leaderstats"
    leaderstats.Parent = player;
end)
```

I want the code to load in all five leaderstats but for some reason it loads in only four leaderstats. There are also no errors in the output widget.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### This is because currently the user list only accepts up to 4 Leaderstats values. The value is still be created and is still accessable through scripts.
Your options are either:

- Use less leaderstat values.
- Create a custom leaderboard, this is what I would recommend if you need these stats to be visible to the player and are willing to spend a reasonable amount of time on a project.

I hope this has been useful.

Comment: TYSMMMMMMMMMMMM